# Looking for n functions $f_n$ that $\frac{\partial f_i(\bar{x})}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij},\;\;\;\;\; f_i(\bar{x})\neq x_i$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for any form for the set of n functions $f_n(\bar{x})$ that depend on the set of variables $\bar{x}\equiv \{ x_i\}\; \forall i=1..n$ and they are defined as

$$
\frac{\partial f_i(\bar{x})}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij},\;\;\;\;\;  f_i(\bar{x})\neq x_i + C_i
$$
where $C_i$ is a constant.
This is the only conditions  and there are no others restriction at all. Functions can be an integral over a new parameter, using complex numbers, the residue theorem etc..
Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: $f_i(x)=x_i+C_i$ where $C_i$ is a constant. Depending on your domain (ie is $f_i$ a function $\mathbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ or from some open subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$?) these should be the only such functions.

Comment: There are no other solutions, unless you allow your domain to be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about functions and as s.harp mentioned in the comments I don't think there are other solutions. But if you look at differential forms and the tangent spaces there is a whole class of 'functions' that fulfill this. To be precise $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \big|_{x_0} : i=1,...,k\}$ form a basis of the tangential space (of $\mathbb{R}^k$) in $x_0$. Now we just need to look for a basis in the cotangential space; we will see that $\{ \text{d}x_i(x_0):i=1,...,k \}$ is such a dual basis. There are great books about differential forms. A classic is 'Differential Forms' by Henri Cartan. I just give some short ideas about this and main definitions/propositions.

**Definition:** $$\begin{align}C_{x_0}&=\{ f:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R} : \exists U \ni x_0 \text{ s.t. $f|_U$ is defined and $f$ is continuous at } x_0\} \\
C^1_{x_0}&=\{ f \in C_{x_0} : f \text{ is differentiable at } x_0 \end{align}$$
$D:C^1_{x_0} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called derivation in $x_0$ if: (i) $D$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, (ii) $D(\mathbb{1})=0$, (iii) $D(f\cdot g)=0$ if $f \in C_{x_0}^1, g \in C_{x_0}, f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$

**Proposition**: The set of all derivations in $x_0$ form a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. We call it tangential space $T_{x_0}$ in $x_0$.

**Proposition**: The derivations $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \big|_{x_0} : i=1,...,k\}$ form a basis of $T_{x_0}$.

**Definition**: Let $E,F$ be normed spaces. Call $\omega$ $p$-differential form if $\omega : U \subset E \to A_p(E,F):=\{ f: \times_{i=1}^p E \to F: f \text{ is alternating, multilinear, continuous} \}$.

**Proposition**: The $1$-differential forms $\{ \text{d}x_i(x_0):i=1,...,k \}$ form a basis of the cotangential space $T_{x_0}^*$ (the algebraic dual space of $T_{x_0}$) and therefore they are a dual basis to $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \big|_{x_0} : i=1,...,k\}$, i.e. $\langle dx_i(x_0),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \big|_{x_0} \rangle = \delta_{i,j}$.

To get an idea of this duality, let $x_0 \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^k\cong T_{x_0}=:E, ~F:=\mathbb{R}$ and look at the $1$-differential form $\omega:U \to A_1(T_{x_0},\mathbb{R}) = T_{x_0}^*$, i.e. $\omega(x_0) \in T_{x_0}^*$. By a representation theorem for $1$-forms we can write $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i dx_i$ where $c_i$ are some functions. Therefore $dx_i$ form a basis of $T_{x_0}^*$. Sometimes we also call these $1$-forms Pfaffian forms.

Now we actually have $dx_i(x_0) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \big|_{x_0} \right) = \delta_{i,j}$ but since we are finite, so everything is nice and $T_{x_0}$ is reflexive we also have what you wanted.

Comment: This is a clearify comment. I think you are absolutly right, the solution are the  basis of the tangential space. I also sure that there are indeed solutions for the problem. Can you provide any example?

Comment: @israel.sincro Example of what exactly? Take the 2D-case; here we have Pfaffians forms like $\omega=A \ \text{d}x_1 + B \ \text{d}x_2$. Now by the dual basis property $\frac{∂}{∂x_1}|_{x_0} ( \text{d}x_1 (x_0) ) =1$ and $\frac{∂}{∂x_2}|_{x_0} ( 42\  \text{d}x_1 (x_0) ) =0$. This concept of differential forms might be quite unsatisfying to you if you expect functions as solutions; I can understand that. This should just be an alternative approach to your question that gives you a whole span of solutions.